# a console code editor with CUA (ctrl-x ctrl-v ...) key bindings (unlike vi)

Tags: editor, console, cua

I'm searching for a console code editor with [CUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) key bindings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> etc.)
Right now i'm toying mcedit but i don't really like it. My desired features are:
* be fast
* [CUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) key bindings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> etc.)
* toggle *show line numbers*
* find/replace/goto line
* bind custom keys to action( ctrl-shift-arrowdown to double the curent line etc.)
* nice simple vi-like interface (no pointless menus)
* be able to programatically extend it ...
etc.

Comment: I do believe that ctrl+x, c, and v are NOT part of the CUA standard, but are Microsoft's bastardisation of the standard. The proper CUA key strokes for these operations are Shift+Delete, Ctrl+Insert and Shift+Insert, as also shown on the linked-to CUA page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use emacs with CUA-mode.
You probably have to configure it further to form it to your liking. 
There are lots of extensions for key-bindings and it has a pretty powerful extension mechanism. If you get over the initial surprise that its all in lisp you might actually like it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number, but most are strangely obscure & little-known. This surprises me -- I'd have thought a lot of people would have wanted this!

I have tried quite a few. These are the only 2 that I know of that are current.

Tilde is alive, maintained and has recent packages available. 
http://os.ghalkes.nl/tilde/

There is also eFTE, enhanced FTE, which works well in my experience.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/efte/

Comment: +1 for tilde. Colour-scheme is a bit old-school, but can be tweaked for a more eye-pleasing experience. Really solid editor, even with mouse support.

Comment: Glad to hear someone else likes it as much as I do!

The colours are DOS-period-authentic and work for me. I am delighted to see it is finding its way into distro repositories. I first found it in openSUSE but more recently I can install it on Ubuntu as well without adding or changing any config.

Answer (score 1):

Try micro editor. See https://micro-editor.github.io/ .

Ctrl-C/V/X/Z/Y/F/S/Q are supported. Shift+Arrows for selection is supported. Syntax highlighting is present.

Another CUA editor, with menu and dialogs, is Turbo, which is written with TurboVision 2.0+Unicode: https://github.com/magiblot/turbo

Comment: I have looked at it, but as far as I can see, it does not have a menu bar or standard dialogues. For me, this renders it largely irrelevant: I do not like to use a UI where I have to memorise commands, because they are not displayed in the standard way. (For comparison this also rules out the Ribbon-based versions of MS Office for me.)

Comment: @LiamProven Try turbo then: https://github.com/magiblot/turbo

Comment: thanks. I am aware of that one, but I have not tried it yet. It does look very promising to me.